# Pegar um retorno de um método em outra classe Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, return

Tenho um método na minha API Spring boot que recebe os dados do usuário que está logando, verifica se existe e se a senha confere. Feito isso o `return` devolve um token JWT. Eu preciso pegar esse retorno do token em outra classe Java. Não estou conseguindo fazer.

Meu método que recebe o usuário e gera o token.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/autenticar", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public LoginResponse autenticar(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios)
        throws ServletException {

    // verifica se foram digitados o login e senha no front end
    if (usuarios.getLogin() == null
            || usuarios.getSenha() == null) {
        throw new  ServletException("Nome ou senha obrigatório");

    }

    // busca no banco de dados
    Usuarios usuariosAutenticado = uService.buscarPorLogin(usuarios.getLogin());

    if (usuariosAutenticado == null) {
        return new LoginResponse("naoEncontrado");
    }       

    // compara a senha vinda do banco de dados com a senha vinda da tela
    if (!usuariosAutenticado.getSenha()
            .equals(usuarios.getSenha())) {
        return new LoginResponse("senhaInvalida");
    }

    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(usuariosAutenticado.getLogin())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "xxx")
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000)).compact();            

    return new LoginResponse(token);
}
```

eu preciso receber o return do token dentro desse método

```
public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
    AuditEntity revEntity = (AuditEntity) revisionEntity;

    //aqui e preciso do token
}
```

Tem como eu fazer isso ???

Comment: Você não poderia adicionar um parâmetro (`String token`) para esse método, guardar uma referência para uma instância da classe desse método no seu `@Controller` e evocar ele dentro do `LoginResponse autenticar(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios)`?

Comment: Não seria mais facil você disponibilizar a classe com o método que gera o token no pool de classes do Spring (`@Component`, `@Service` ou `@Repository`) e obter a classe e invocar o método onde precisa?

Comment: Boa tarde, tudo bem? Acredito que o jeito mais fácil de resolver seu problema seria atribuir esse valor de retorno a um atributo da classe de método, e então com a construção de um GET você poderia obter esse valor.

Comment: Na classe que tem o método `autenticar`, quais são as anotações que você colocou? O método `newRevision(Object)` está nesta mesma classe?